# Make Stack Overflow use HTTPS always

Tags: feature-request

I do notice that Stack Overflow (or rather, Stack Exchange in general) can be accessed with either http or https, why not make http redirect to https instead?

**Edit:** Well, this works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/